# Does plaster-based drywall exist?

Tags: drywall

Does plaster-based drywall exist? Normal drywall is made using gypsum, not plaster. Is it possible to get a drywall that is made out of genuine plaster, not gypsum.

The reason I ask is that find gypsum dust (calcium sulfate) slightly irritating, probably because it has sulfur in it.

Comment: Not trying to slam china here but a few years back close to hurricane Katrina  the Chinese were shipping drywall that had massive amounts, so much so that it was eating the copper pipes and wiring. I thought it was sulfur or pot-ash I don’t remember for sure but some people were affected also. the issue could be the manufacturer more than the product itself as something to look into leaving as a comment as I did not run into this but it was wide spread for a while especially in the disaster area.

Comment: "drywall that had massive amounts, so" massive amounts of what, @EdBeal?

Comment: You could use cement board. Heavier, more expensive, harder to work with, but should alleviate the gypsum problem. Or... wear a dust mask.

Comment: @freeman can you not read the post ? The next sentence states I was not sure if sulfur or pot ash. Cement board really? Have you ever purchased or used cement board freeman?

Comment: I sure did read your whole commend, @EdBeal, and was still confused. And yes, I've used cement board - I noted the disadvantages in my comment. To my knowledge, there's no gypsum in it, though, so it would solve the OPs immediate problem. It may involve _other_ issues (which I noted), but would solve this one.

Comment: I am sorry but you are suggesting a cement product and guess what modern cement uses the same material: from ACI technical questions: for modern cement the rate of stiffening of the cement should be controlled within limits to make cement useful . This is done by controlling the amount of calcium sulfate (gypsum [CaSO4.2H2O]) or gypsum with anhydride [CaSO4] added to the cement as it is being ground. Have you ever heard the term add 2% calcium to speed up the cure of concrete ? Guess what that is gypsum and concrete has gypsum so no cement board is not a good option!

Comment: Is your concern based on having to install it? Or just living in a house with it? You should not be experiencing dust from drywall after it is installed.

Comment: There is no "sulfur" in gypsum , it contains sulfate . Same as table salt is sodium chloride , not chlorine.

Comment: @ blacksmith some of the Chinese drywall may have had sulfur and or  strontium. The install timeline was 2001 through 2008. As of 2015 over 4000 complaints had been reported in 44 states. Searching  “Chinese drywall health problems” or   property damage from Chinese drywall there are many articles I found this info on nolo it looks like a legal type site and I am not trying to advertise them so I did not provide the complete link. that one looked legit compared to others I looked at.

Answer (score 1):

Plaster would be too brittle to be put into a board format like drywall. Plaster is applied wet over a lath or mesh to hold it up and then dries hard.

Drywall is not supposed to have Sulphur in it, but as mentioned in a comment by Ed Beal, there was a lot of bad drywall sold in North America from China that did, and it is causing lots of problems all over. The Sulphur outgasses and causes corrosion of copper wire and pipes. Some insurance companies are now refusing to underwrite houses known to be built with it unless it is removed.

Comment: Are there health risks associated with the bad drywall as well?

Answer (score 0):

I am not aware of any plaster-based wall board.

That being said, you could look into blue board (on which, a plaster veneer is applied), if it's plaster you're looking for.

Unfortunately in your case, blue board is still gypsum-based if you're working with it.